# How can I display a SQL Server XML column as hyperlink in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

I have a XML column in SQL Server that is returned in my datasource used by a SSRS report.  Is there a way to display a hyperlink in the SSRS report column that displays the XML in a new window when the user clicks on it?

I want a "cleaner" display of the XML data then dumping it out in the report column but I need the user to be able to view the full contents of the XML column if they want to.  This would be very similar to how SQL Server displays XML column data in SQL Server Management Studio where you see some of the XML data and it is hyperlinked so you can click on it to view the full XML in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you display the xml data in a textbox. I suggest that you create a second report in which the full xml is displayed. In your existing report you could add an "Action" on your textbox which refers to that newly created report. You can limit the size of the xml displayed in with the LEFT() function. You might need to convert the xml in a string first by using CSTR(). Unfortunately I do not have a SSRS here (not working on Boxing Day :-)) to test it out myself.

Hope this helps.